# Identify if records exist in another dataframe, within the first dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have two csv files, OrderOne (approx 105k records) & OrderTwo (approx 115k records)

I want to add a column in OrderTwo which states "TRUE" if that record is found in OrderOne, and "FALSE" if not.

The new column should be appended and the file output.

There is no shared key, so I'm creating one.  It will the concatenation of columns within the orders, which are in different formats from different suppliers.  For simplicity in this example, it will be 'Forename' + 'Surname'.

I am reading the two data tables in, one of which I only need a few columns from.  I'm converting names to upper case & stripping out white space to ensure they match correctly.

I've read the outputs from these files and they look correct. So far, so good.

```
import pandas as pd

orderoneData = pd.read_csv ('orderone.csv', usecols=['Customer Reference','Forename', 'Surname'], index_col=False)
orderoneData.set_index('Customer Reference', inplace=True)
orderoneData["FNSN"] = orderoneData['Forename'].str.strip() + orderoneData["Surname"].str.strip()
orderoneData["FNSN"] = orderoneData["FNSN"].str.upper()

ordertwoData = pd.read_csv ('ordertwo.csv')
ordertwoData.set_index('Supplier Reference', inplace=True)
ordertwoData["FNSN"] = ordertwoData['Forename'].str.strip() + ordertwoData["Surname"].str.strip()
ordertwoData["FNSN"] = ordertwoData["FNSN"].str.upper()
```

Next I'm merging; I'm using OrderTwo as the left (because that's the file I want the new column added to). I intend to change the values of the indicator to Boolean ('both' = True, otherwise False) but I haven't got that far yet.

```
d = (
    ordertwoData.merge(orderoneData['FNSN'], 
              on=['FNSN'],
              how='left', 
              indicator=True,
              )
)

d.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

At this point, I have far too many records (approx 179k; I'm expecting the same as OrderTwo, which is 115k).  My understanding was that a left join should have the same number of records as the left table, which is my case is ordertwoData
#I thought I might have used the wrong merge criteria and it was creating duplicates, so I thought I would just remove them

```
d1 = d.drop_duplicates()
print(d1)
d1.to_csv("d.csv")
```

Dropping duplicates leaves me with too few records, so I'm confused how I get the right result.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I think there is an mistake in choosing the shared key. It can be that they have the same FNSN value but actually different rows. For the FNSN value in df1 there is more than one FNSN  value in df2. This creates a separate row for each combination. You need an unique id column.

Comment: @Clegane that's a great point.  There are unique identifiers for both data files and I have set those as the reference, however they are not shared so I cannot use these references to identify the records. Is there a way to ensure that the end result matches the OrderTwo data shape precisely, even if there are duplicates? Thank you

Comment: Is there a possibility that `'Customer Reference','Forename', 'Surname']` values ​​for both dataframes are the same but  actually different order ? you can define an id column using these three columns.

Comment: @Clegane FYI I was able to solve this by dropping duplicates on the OrderTwo reference number after merging.  Thanks for your help identifying the real cause of the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Clegane identified, the issue here was not the code but the input data containing duplicate records. By including the original reference in the merge then dropping duplicates on OrderTwo['Supplier Reference'] I got the expected answer. Thanks!